# Show sup(A) is in F, where F is closed and open

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

This question is worded very strangely and honestly I'm rather confused.

Suppose $\varnothing$ $\subsetneq$ *F* $\subsetneq$ $\mathbb{R}$ is closed. Then $\exists$ *x*$_{0}$ $\in$ *F* and *y$_{0}$* $\in$ *F$^{c}$*.

We will assume that *x*$_{0}$<*y$_{0}$* without loss of generality.

The set *A*:={*x* $\in$ *F*: *x*<*y$_{0}$*} is bounded above by *y$_{0}$* and nonempty since *x*$_{0}$ $\in$ *A*. As such, *z*:= sup(*A*) exists.

Show *z* $\in$ *F*.

My professor mentioned that this had something to do with proving that $\varnothing$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are the only "clopen" subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, but that's not actually mentioned anywhere in the question.

Comment: Your professor is wrong. A topological space has only two "clopen" is equivalent to say the topological space is connected (this is a tautology).

Comment: @WillM. But $\mathbb R$ *is* connected (under the Euclidean metric).  And it's only clopen sets *are* $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb R$

Comment: The result doesn't seem to be related right away with connectedness. I wouldn't know how to prove _it is not_ related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z \in F^c$ then  $z\not \in F$ and $z \not \in A$.  But $z$ is $\sup A$ so for every $\epsilon$ there is a $x \in A \subset F$ so that $z-\epsilon < x \le z$ but as $x \in A$, $x \ne z$ so $z-\epsilon < x < z$.

So $z$ is a limit point of $F$.  But $F$ is closed. So $z \in F$.  A contradiction.

So $z\in F$.

Not sure that this anything to do with clopen sets though.  At least not immediately.

Comment: We don't assume $y_0$ is an upper bound of $F$.

Comment: Neither did I.  $y_0$ is an upper bound of $A \subset F$.

Comment: Sure, but I don't understand how you claim that $z\geq y_0$.

Comment: Because if $z \not \in F$ then $z \not \in A$.

Comment: Ok, but if $F=[0,1]$, $y_0=100$, then $A=F$ and $z=1<100=y_0$.

Comment: Ha, i see.  My bad.  Doesn't matter though.

Comment: That's true. All that matters is that $z\leq y_0$.

Comment: Not even that.  You just need A to be upper bounded.